# Split a string into sets of twos

Tags: python, string, split

I want to split a string into sets of twos, e.g.

```
['abcdefg']
```

to

```
['ab','cd','ef']
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
string = 'acabadcaa\ndarabr'
newString = []

for i in string:
    newString.append(string[i:i+2])
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm thinking of slicing using a for loop as such:    string = 'acabadcaa\ndarabr'
newString = []

for i in string:
    newString.append(string[i:i+2])

Comment: That's good try to slice and if you'll had problems or exceptions post it so we can help.

Comment: thanks everyone loads of help

Answer (score 2):

One option using regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'..', 'abcdefg')
['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
```

`re.findall` returns a list of all non-overlapping matches from a string. `'..'` says match any two consecutive characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
def splitCount(s, count):
     return [''.join(x) for x in zip(*[list(s[z::count]) for z in range(count)])]

splitCount('abcdefg',2)
```

Comment: This is an answer to the question, but if the OP doesn't know how to slice i don't think he will understand `zip`, `join` or list comprehension, an explanation would be nice at this case.

Answer (score 1):

To split a string `s` into a list of (guaranteed) equally long substrings of the length n, and truncating smaller fragments:

```
n = 2
s = 'abcdef'
lst = [s[i:i+n] for i in xrange(0, len(s)-len(s)%n, n)]

['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this outputs `['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'g']` which is not quite what OP specified.

Answer (score 0):

This function will get any `chunk` :

```
def chunk(s,chk):
    ln = len(s)
    return [s[i:i+chk] for i in xrange(0, ln - ln % chk, chk)]  

 In [2]: s = "abcdefg"

In [3]: chunk(s,2)
Out[3]: ['ab', 'cd', 'ef']

In [4]: chunk(s,3)
Out[4]: ['abc', 'def']

In [5]: chunk(s,5)
Out[5]: ['abcde']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
s = "abcdefg"
newList = [s[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(s)-1,2)]
```